# JSON object values cannot be accessed using key names in JS

Tags: javascript, json, object, websocket, binance

i am trying to get data from Binance web sockets in my react app

```js
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethbtc@trade");
ws.onopen = () => {
  ws.send(
    JSON.stringify({
      method: "SUBSCRIBE",
      params: ["ethbtc@trade"],
      id: 13
    })
  );
};
ws.onmessage = evnt => {
  console.log(evnt.data);
};
```

and the response is
`{"e":"trade","E":1593865856744,"s":"ETHBTC","t":180904813,"p":"0.02493100","q":"0.90600000","b":788853315,"a":788853661,"T":1593865856743,"m":true,"M":true}`

but **when trying to get a specific value from the above object it shows undefined !**

```
console.log(evnt.data.s)
```

it shows **undefined**

if anyone can help it will be great, Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the result of `console.log(typeof event.data)`?

Comment: maybe the response data is String. If it is string, you need to parse before accessing it

Comment: @Mitya It is showing String !

Comment: OK so your data isn't an object - needs parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try like this

1. console.log(evnt.data["s"])
   Or,
2. console.log(JSON.parse(evnt.data).s)
   Or,
3. console.log(evnt.data.toObject().s)

Comment: Thank You console.log(JSON.parse(evnt.data).s) the second one works for me !

Comment: It's my pleasure.
can you please knock me here?
link: https://www.facebook.com/talha.aiubian

Comment: i stopped using fb :-(..no more account !

Comment: How can I contact with you?

Comment: linkedin.com/in/aashiqotp/ or instagram : @Aashiq_Otp

Answer (score 1):

try this may be it solves your problem

```
JSON.parse(event.data).s
```